# One Loop does not work at all ,why?

Tags: gfortran

I want to ask if anybody knows why the first loop of this program that I have written in Fortran  does not work at all. For `do r = 0, 5, 0.1` just the first number of `r` is read `r=0`. And what can I do for make it possible?

```fortran
implicit none

real , allocatable ::x(:)
real , allocatable ::y(:)
real , allocatable ::h(:)
integer i , n , a , j , d  
real hp1 , s , c , r      
real , allocatable ::T1(:)

open (10,file='point.txt', status='old')
open (6,file='pointr2.txt',status='new') 

read (10,*) n

allocate (x(n))
allocate (y(n))
allocate (h(n)) 
allocate (T1(n))

s=0
d=0
c=0

do r=0.0000 , 5.0000 , 0.1
  do j= 1, n
    if ( j.gt.1 ) goto 39
    do i=1,n
      read (10,*)  x(i), y(i), h(i)
      write (6,*) x(i), y(i), h(i)
    end do

    close (10)
    call highest ( h,n,hp1,a )
    write (6,*) hp1 
    write (6,*) ' The First highest point number' , a  
    write (6,*)  x(a)

    39 if ( j.eq. a ) goto 100

    s=abs((h(j)-h(a))/(x(j)-x(a)))
    d=((x(j)-x(a))**2+(y(j)-y(a))**2+(h(j)-h(a))**2)**0.5
    c=((x(j)-x(a))**2+(y(j)-y(a))**2)
    T1(j)=atan((y(a)-y(j))/(x(a)-x(j)))

    if ( c .eq.r**2 .and. d .ge. 0.0025 .and.s.ge.0.and.s .le. 0.04) then
      T1(j)=  atan((y(a)-y(j))/(x(a)-x(j)))
      write (6,*) 'Group 1' , j  ,T1(j) 
    end if                               
    write (6,*) s, c ,T1(j)  
    100 end do 
  end    
do
end

subroutine highest ( h,n,hp1,a )
  implicit none

  integer i , n ,a 
  real hp1  
  real h(n)  
  hp1=h(1)
  a= 1

  do i=1,n
    if ( h(i) .gt.hp1  ) then
      hp1=h(i) 
      a = i  
    end if 
  end do 
end subroutine
```

My input is :

```
6
0.01     0.02        0.03
0.13     0.14        0.1504
0.04     0.05        0.06
0.07     0.08        0.15  
0.10     0.11        0.12
0.15     0.042020410 0.15
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please format code your code properly by editing. Code that is indented by 4 spaces will be parsed as code (or you can select it and hit the `{}` button). Please only paste the relevant portions of your code (and desired input) and mention all relevant debugging-related information you might have. Questions applicable only to a specific issue are liable to eventually to be deleted, so debugging the question down to a very specific issue can only help.

Answer (score 3):

You are closing unit 10 at the first iteration of the inner loop and never opening it again:

```
close (10)   <------ HERE
call highest ( h,n,hp1,a )
write (6,*) hp1
```

Thus in the second iteration of the outer `do` loop the program tries to read from a closed unit. In most compilers this leads to an implicit `OPEN` statement issued on a file named `fort.10` which most certainly does not exist. `gfortran` creates such files with zero length and hence an immediate EOF is hit while trying to read from it and your program fails.

To prevent this you should move the code that reads from `point.txt` and fills `x(i)`, `y(i)` and `h(i)` outside the loop.

Also note that Fortran 95 introduced the requirement that everything in the DO loop control should be of scalar `INTEGER` type, i.e. `do r=0.0000 , 5.0000 , 0.1` isn't allowed by F95 and later. `gfortran` would not compile your program if you provide the `-std=f95` option switch:

```
do r=0.0000 , 5.0000 , 0.1
   1
Error: Deleted feature: Loop variable at (1) must be integer
```